# ¿Cómo elimino el caracter "[" de un string?

Tags: java, str-replace

lo que ocurre es que estoy intentando quitar el caracter `"["` de un string que tiene `"[5"` pero no he logrado hacerlo, esto es lo que he intentado:

```
cadena.replaceAll("\\[", "");
```

O esto

```
cadena.replace("[", "");
```

No se que puedo hacer, y consultando por ahí no he dado con una solución. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se te habrá olvidado asignárselo a la variable.

```
cadena=cadena.replaceAll("\\[", "");
```

Comment: Definitivamente, me siento tonto, no se porque no se me había ocurrido, depronto la presión que tenia encima en ese momento no me ayudo a pensar. Muchas Gracias :D